# rails, overriding bootstraps rules in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, twitter-bootstrap, overriding

hello im having trouble overriding bootstraps framework when it goes into a production server. on my local machine im able to override it but by putting it on heroku, it reverts back to twitters bootstrap rules.

for example, ive been trying to override

```
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class => "input-medium search-query" %>
```

i have a custom.css.scss file in my stylesheets folder, which then gets compiled from my application.css because i do a ...

```
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
```

on my custom.css.scss, i did

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

on the top. im able to override the length of input bar two different ways.

i could override the input-medium class by having

```
.input-medium{ width:300px !important }
```

or add a class to it such as .expand

```
.expand{ width:300px !important; }
```

the form would then look like

```
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class => "input-medium search-query expand" %>
```

unfortunately these changes only appear on my local machine. when i push to heroku, it seems like it reverts back to twitters rules. can anyone help please?

thank you = )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're re-compiling your assets every time you push to Heroku after you've made a change in your CSS or JS.  Try doing this:

`RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`

After that's done, push to GitHub (or whatever), and then push to Heroku.  Your changes should then be visible.